# Showing records based on topic

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

I got a problem with showing things when pressing on a `topic`.

**What I want**

I want too show the records out of the [second database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etauk.png) that has the correct `topic_id` so if you click on a topic it needs to only show the "onderwerpen"(dutch for subjects) that have that `topic_id`

My code:

```
<div class="box box-info">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Topics</h3>
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
 $toppics = $app->get_topics();
   foreach($toppics as $topic){
     echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
echo '<div class="well dash-box">';
echo '<h3>'.$topic['onderwerp'].'</h3><br>'; 
echo '<a href="####">'  .$topic['omschrijving'].'</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>

</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.box -->
```

Function I use:

```
public function get_topics(){
   $getTopic = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
    $topics = $this->database->resultset();

    return $topics;

 }
```

[The topic database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsmbe.png)

[The `onderwerpen` database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etauk.png)

After clicking on a subject It now shows all the "onderwerpen" out of the database
The code for that:

```
<?php

          $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
          foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp){
            echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
                if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'])) { 
                    echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'].'/'.$onderwerp['foto'].'" />';
                } else {
                    echo '<i style="font-size: 2.5em;" class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>';
                }
                echo '<b><a href="https:/####/reactie"> '.$onderwerp['onderwerpnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
                echo ' - ' . $onderwerp['voornaam'] . ' ' . $onderwerp['achternaam'];
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Get_onderwerpen function:

```
    public function get_onderwerpen(){
        $getOnderwerp = $this->database->query("
        SELECT onderwerpen.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM onderwerpen 
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON onderwerpen.klant_id=klanten.id
        ORDER BY id ASC");
        $onderwerpen = $this->database->resultset();

        return $onderwerpen;

    }
```

Comment: show us the get_onderwerpen() function

Comment: @MehrdadEP added it to the question

Comment: Have you tried using some `JOIN`s to solve the problem?

Comment: ok you have to send topic_id as an argument to get_onderwerpen() function and use it in sql query as where statement

Comment: what do you mean with "you have to send topic_id as an agrument to get_onderwerpen" ? @MehrdadEP

Comment: get_onderwerpen() should return all subjects with specific topic_id

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to your select: `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE blabla.id = $_GET['topic_id'] ORDER BY  ...`.  Like @MehrdadEP said.